# Looping a video on Firebase storage cost data?

Tags: swift, firebase, video, avfoundation, firebase-storage

I store 30 sec video files in firebase storage with a url string in the realtime database. If I loop a video in my app, will it cost extra data every time it loops? If the answer is yes, is there any way I can cache the video like I cache the image?

This is to play the video:

```
if let url = URL(string: videoUrl) {
        player = AVPlayer(url: url)

        playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer?.frame = frame
        bubbleView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
        playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
        player?.play()
    }
```

I use notification to loop:

```
@objc private func playItemDidPlayToEnd(nitification: Notification) {

   playerLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspect
   player?.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
   player?.play()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Storage charges for the amount of data you download from it.

So if the library/player you use downloads the data for each time it plays/loops the video, you will pay for each.

On the other hand, if the library/player locally caches the data the first time it downloads it, and plays it from the local cache afterwards, you'd only pay once.

From what I can find, caching does not seem to be the default behavior of `AVPlayer`, but there's some good [articles and libraries on how to enable caching](https://www.google.com/search?q=swift+AVPlayer+cache&oq=swift+AVPlayer+cache).